# iframe to factorize code in static web sites?

Tags: html, iframe, methodology

I'm making a web site and due to bureaucratic limitations I am limited to use static web pages.

I would like to include a header and a footer in all of them.

Would it be acceptable to use iframes in this case or should I repeat that code in all of them? Is there any other possibility?

It's not big deal, I simply don't know what is the best practice in this case.

Thank you very much.

PS: I'm also uncertain whether I should ask this in programmers.stackexchange.com it's hard for me to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is generally referred to as an "include". Server side programming languages like PHP and others offer this functionality. All you have to do is create a header or footer file with the common code on it and then "include" it into each page you want to use it.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I can't use any server side programming languages that generate the html code dynamically, I am limited to static web pages.

I can use one of those to generate the web pages and then upload them, that would be the "repeat the code" possibility, I would simply repeat it in an automated way, not manually.

Is this your suggestion?

Comment: If you can't use server side code you really don't have many options left and none of them are ideal. Your option would work and be user/search engine friendly. The only catch is if you ever need to make a change to a header or footer you'll need to do a search & replace on every file you've generated so far.

Comment: Maybe I could re-generate them automatically, I think I'll try to use a server side technology and then dump those pages into the directory I have. I have ftp access, so I can automate that too. I'll probably use Python for everything. Thank you.